# Passing HTTPS POST parameters for authentication

Tags: python, https

```html
<h2 class="block-title">
  <img class="img img-16 img-grey-down"
       src="https://sstatic.fotolia.com/v2010/pics/all/img/clear.gif"
       alt="arrow" />
  I already have an account
  <span class="block-title-right"></span>
</h2>

<div class="block-content">
  <p>Welcome back!</p>
  <form action="/Member/Login" method="post">
    <div class="form login-form mini-form">

      <div class="form-line on">
        <label class="form-label" for="login">
          Login <span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="" class="form-text" tabindex="1" />
        <div class="cb"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-line">
        <label class="form-label" for="password">
          Password <span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="form-text" tabindex="2" />
        <div class="cb"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-line remember-form-line on">
        <a class="form-lost" href="http://www.fotolia.com/Member/ForgotPassword">
          Forgot password?
        </a>
        <label class="form-label" for="remember_me">
          <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" value="1" class="form-checkbox" tabindex="3" />
          Remember me
        </label>
        <div class="cb"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-action">
        <input type="submit" name="signin" id="signin" value="Login " class="button button-S-L color-1-button" tabindex="4" />
        <div class="cb"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Hi! I am trying to post the variables login credentials but unfortunately, it is not giving me the after-login page *(the page that we get after successful login)*, presently the code is like this:

```python
import os 
import httplib, urllib 
import urllib import urllib2


def file_write(filename, text_to_write):   
    f = open(filename, 'w')  
    f.write(text_to_write)   
    f.close() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://www.fotolia.com/Member/Login'
    user_agent ='Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
    values = {
        'login': 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
        'password': 'Random123',
    }
    headers = {'User-Agent': "some-user-agent"}

    data = urllib.urlencode(values)   
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)   
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)   
    the_page = response.read()   
    file_write('output.html', the_page)
```

#### The problem:

The processing page does not have a file extension, let see here the form action is written as /Member/Login ? And the protocol is HTTPS, how I am supposed to handle this situation.

Comment: Please format the code you are pasting correctly (4 spaces at the beginning of the line format the code as actual code, one `>` symbol at the beginning formats the line as quote instead). Also please describe what exactly these code parts are, do not make others guess.

Comment: -1 for not giving properly formatted question, which in turn shows lack of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
values = {
           'login' :'XXXXXXXXXXX',
           'password' : 'Random123',
           'submit' : 'Login',
         }
```